# How to read excel of particular template from a folder and log errors using kettle

Tags: excel, pentaho, kettle

I want to read excel files from a folder. Each excel is of same template
Eg.

```
|| Emp_id || Name || HRA || DA || NetPay ||
```

If there is an excel which doesn't match with the header it should log error.
How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Step One : right a Java Program to compare the headers of the two files and then run this program using  "pan " or Shell return  a value to the Remort file location in the Text file .
Step Two :-
Status as :- "COLUMN MATCHED"
             "COLUMN MISMATCHED"
use **Write to files step **

get this value from the Remort location and Store in a Variable using Java script .

check if value matches then process the ETL else send a Error message as shown on the Image
[image]